# Using jwt generation jsrsasign in server script with Rhino

Tags: javascript, jwt, google-oauth, rhino

I need to do a JWT to request authorization to Google. Because of the design, it will need to be done on a server script running on Rhino and I have no access to node.js. Google requires a RSA SHA-256 algorithm.

- jsrsasign needs the navigator object available to run
- cryptojs does not do a RSA
- cryptico needs a browser (client script)

At this point I reach a big roadblock, not sure if I will ever be able to do this.

Comment: there are other implementations, check out https://jwt.io/

Comment: @AndréWerlang, thanks that was my first hit when I first started my research. That site pointed me to the jsrsasign library.

Comment: as you ruled out node.js, take a look at other platforms. that's what I meant. what is available to you on the server?

Comment: JavaScript runs in Rhino. I can load javascript libraries, so far the ones I have found require to run in a client script and they use the navigator object. Other libraries like cryptojs do not do a RSA SHA256.

Comment: Any reason to omit Rhino in the question itself?

Comment: Perhaps you could use https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken, or in jsrsasign, see uses of navigator and stub it: https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=navigator&type=

Comment: You are right! https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/blob/master/npm/lib/jsrsasign.js is what works on a server script! Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @AndréWerlang, should I answer my own question? I am new to posting and answering questions.

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andre Werlang for the help.

Here is the library that works:

github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/blob/master/npm/lib/jsrsasign.js

Works like a charm:
KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('RS256', header, claim, private_key);